# Sharing OWIN Cookie Across ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, owin

I have an existing ASP.NET WebForms application that is currently using Forms Authentication.  We are building a new site in ASP.NET Core 2 that is a virtual directory in IIS.  We need the authentication to be shared across both sites so that users don't have to login twice.

I have configured the .NET Core app to use cookie authentication as follows:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "cred";
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login");
        options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Logout");
    });
```

On login, the cookie is being created with this code and the user is signed in successfully:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
    new Claim("FullName", $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.UserType),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.EmailAddress),
};

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
return new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

var _authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    IsPersistent = true,
    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60),
    AllowRefresh = true
};
await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, _authenticationProperties);
```

In my WebForms app, I have set Authentication to None on the web.config and configured it to use Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies and Interop as follows:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    CookieName = "cred",
    AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/LoginPage.aspx"),
    CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager(), //Owin and ASP.NET do not play nicely with Response Cookies.  Remove at your peril,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
    TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(
        new DataProtectorShim(
            DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\keys\"), (builder) => { builder.SetApplicationName("Aliss");})
                .CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "Cookies", "v2"))),
});
```

Comment: Not sure if [Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop/) is of any help, but worth taking a look.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?